# Install pyCurl on Pypy

Tags: pypy, pycurl

I am trying to install the compiled version of PyCurl, but I get the error:

[image]

My system configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "cp37" part in the first error message is the hint: it means "CPython 3.7".  That's a compiled package (a "wheel") that can only be installed on CPython 3.7, not on PyPy.  You need to install from sources, or find a wheel for PyPy.